# How to connect to a google cloud sql instance from AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to some database located in Google Cloud SQL from a java web application deployed on AWS Elasic Beanstalk (with Eclipse), using the JDBC method.

```
String url = ConfigUtilities.getProperty("DATABASE_CONNN_URL_" + mode);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, ConfigUtilities.getProperty("USERNAME_DB_" + mode),
                ConfigUtilities.getProperty("PASSWORD_DB_" + mode));
```

The url looks like this

```
DATABASE_CONNN_URL_PRODUCTION=jdbc:google:mysql://project-name:europe-west1:instance-name/db-name
```

I have  the following jar attached: mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar (located in lib folder under WEB-INF).

I get the following error

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:google:mysql://project-name:europe-west1:instance-name/db-name
```

The same application deployed in App Engine works.

Comment: please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java

Answer (score 0):

snippet from [Connecting to Cloud SQL from External Applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#java)
The JDBC socket factory provides an alternative to the client-side proxy software, and **requires the Cloud SQL API to be enabled**, just as the proxy does. It authenticates with Cloud SDK credentials, so the **Cloud SDK must be installed and authenticated.**

examples/compute-engine/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/sql/mysql/example/ListTables.java

> String jdbcUrl = String.format(
>          "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
>               + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
>            databaseName,
>           instanceConnectionName);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);